# How to store list of realm object to Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-list

how do i convert list of realm object to List> ?

I have List data and i want to convert this to List>

My realm object class:

```
public Integer LaborMiscTimeID;
public String MobileUniqueID;
public Integer DriverID;
```

Comment: Why don't you use the list of realm objects directly?

Comment: `RealmResults` already implements `List`.

Comment: ya. it works. actually my issue was related to scrolling. thought realmlist is causing any issue. now i found the actual solution. Thanks for reply.